# How to scale VirtualBox to fit the screen size?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I use VirtualBox OSE 4.0.4 r70112

I used to maximize VirtualBox before, it always works after installing Guest Additions.

But I don't know why now it doesn't work.

Just like this picture (1562x864):

[image]

When I tune to 1920x955, it becomes too large:

[image]

How can I just make it fit the screen size?

Answer (score 6):

I found that I can click <kbd>Host</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make it fit the screen size.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, Host+F, but it will go to Full Screen mode. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

**MacOSX Catalina, v10.15.5**

Vbox 6.1

Your solutions might be

- <kbd>Host</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Host</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>
- <kbd>Host</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I got the desired results with "View > Auto-resize Guest Display".

This way the guest display adapts to the size of the host window where it's running.

Just make sure you have Guest Additions installed and have done an appropriate number of reboots of the guest...